# Windows Phone 8 Continue parent scrolling

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a Windows Phone 8 application (please note that it's not 8.1) and I have the following struggle.
I have a page containing a StackPanel. Within the StackPanel there are several objects like buttons, textboxes and a LongListSelector.
The LongListSelector is bound to an ItemsSource. Because it can contain a lot of items I had to set the MaxHeight (otherwise it exceeds the limit of 2000px of vertical screen space) 
However when scrolling the page down I stumble upon the LongListSelector. I can than scroll the LongListSelector too, which is fine. But when I scroll to the end of the LongListSelector it won't 'snap' to the StackPanel so it just leaves the page there and doesn't continue with scrolling to StackPanel.

A short code example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button />
    <TextBlock />
    <TextBox />
    <Button />
    <LongListSelector>
       This contains a bunch of items
    <LongListSelector/>
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

So what happends is.. I can scroll the complete page to the LongListSelector. I can scroll the LongListSelector. But when I'm at the end of the LongListSelector.. It wont continu scrolling the page. 
So I never see the last TextBox (in this example that is)

I've also tried replacing the LongListSelector with a ListBox but that doesn't make any difference.

Hope that someone can help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

From your Question what I understood is that the total height by summing up your UI Elements is more than the Page Height. If you put a ScrollViewer Tag at the start and End of StackPanel. It will work just fine. In ListBox and LongListSelector it is implied.

`<ScrollViewer>
      <StackPanel>
       <Button />
     <TextBlock />
      <TextBox />
      <Button />
       <LongListSelector>
       This contains a bunch of items
      <LongListSelector/>
      <TextBox />
     </StackPanel>
     </ScrollViewer>`

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this does not solve the issue.
I can scroll the entire page, but when I'm at the end of the LongListSelector it doesn't scroll the rest of the page. Than I have to tap the screen outside the LongListSelector box to continu scrolling the page.